# How to see the logs of an application inside a docker?

Tags: docker, containers

If I am creating a docker image for one of my applications and publishing it in docker hub.

This image was downloaded by many users and ran that application in their containers and that generated application logs in a folder.

Now as a developer how can I see those application logs from my machine when that container is in remote computer for which I dont have access?

If it is a virtual machine, I can do ssh to that same machine and go to that folder anse see the logs for that particular application, so how it is possible with docker?

I am not talking about docker event logs, the logs generated by my python application with the logging module. Could you please help me on how to handle this case in dockers.

I don't have any experience with working on dockers.

Comment: Open a shell in the machine and cat the logs: "docker exec -it container-name-here bash". You can use sh if bash is not available in the container.

Comment: Can I login to the same docker used by end user in his machine and see the logs from my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker exec` can be used to run bash commands in a docker container. But in your case the containers are running in a remote machine and not in your local machine. So, in that case, you have 2 options.
1. ssh into the remote machine and then use docker exec command to check the logs.
2. Directly ssh to the docker container.

But, in both scenarios, you will need SSH access to the remote machines from the end users. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, if it is a virtual machine, then I can login to it as it is on cloud, but if docker container is on a physical machine for which user does not want to give us the access, how do I access it. Will it not be a disadvantage of docker?

Comment: You mentioned that you could have login to the virtual machine as it is on cloud, and you will require the credentials for that, won't you, which you will get only from the user who has deployed that virtual machine on cloud. It sounds almost the same to me. It's not a question about what you are using, docker or  virtual machine, but rather where it is running.

Answer (score 1):

If your application writes log files to the container filesystem, this is one of a couple of good uses for Docker bind mounts.  If *the operator* (the person running the container; not you, the original software author) starts the container with

```
docker run -v $PWD/logs:/app/logs ... you/yourimage
```

then they will be able to read the log files directly on their host system.

As the original application developer, you have no access to these logs.  This is the same as every other (non-SaaS) application: the end user installs software on their system and runs it, but it's on a system you can't log into, so you can't directly see things like log files.  The techniques for dealing with this are the same as anything else: when a user files a bug report make sure they provide a sufficient reproduction, log files, and relevant configuration, and reproduce the issue yourself locally.